# Can we convert 32 bit library file to 64 bit library file?

Tags: linux, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I have some 32 bit library files (.a files) in Solaris. I am porting my application to 64 bit Linux environment. Is there any way to convert the 32 bit libraries to 64 bit or should I regenerate the libraries in 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

It is not just a question of 32-bit vs 64-bit. It's also a question of Solaris versus Linux. These are two operating systems that have different calling conventions and different ABIs. That means things like sizes of data types can be different, the way the compiler puts stuff in registers and on the stack to do a function call is different, the way system calls are done is different, etc.

It is probably possible to convert a static library in the way you want, in some cases, but you would need to write the tools yourself. Compiling from source is way easier, much more reliable, and also something you need to be able to do at will anyway (otherwise you can't easily fix problems in the library, e.g., security issues).

Answer (score 2):

No; you have to recompile them for 64-bit, because a lot of necessary information is lost during the compilation.

Good luck.